# I cant seem to figure out the problem with this game in wine

Tags: wine, games, steam

I have been trying to get Disgaea PC to work in wine, but i cant seem to get it to work.

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x60ed0c7c).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:60ed0c7c ESP:0033ef90 EBP:00000000 EFLAGS:00210202(  R- --  I   - - - )
 EAX:7c3172f0 EBX:7c3172d0 ECX:00000008 EDX:00000000
 ESI:7c82c07c EDI:00000008
Stack dump:
0x0033ef90:  34b92c70 34b92c70 60ed0c39 7c828308
0x0033efa0:  60d64790 7c825b40 00000000 60d647c7
0x0033efb0:  00000008 00000000 00000000 7c82c07c
0x0033efc0:  7c8254d0 00000000 60d64795 60d676f2
0x0033efd0:  00000008 00000000 0000000a 60ed2236
0x0033efe0:  7c303168 7c828178 00000000 7c82c07c
Backtrace:
=>0 0x60ed0c7c in i965_dri.so (+0x18dc7c) (0x00000000)
  1 0x60d647c7 in i965_dri.so (+0x217c6) (0x00000000)
  2 0x60d676f2 in i965_dri.so (+0x246f1) (0x00000000)
  3 0x60ed2709 in i965_dri.so (+0x18f708) (0xffffffb0)
  4 0x7a89aa59 glDrawArrays+0x78() in opengl32 (0x0033f088)
  5 0x00421122 in dis1_st (+0x21121) (0x0033f0dc)
  6 0x0042747b in dis1_st (+0x2747a) (0x0033f120)
  7 0x00426724 in dis1_st (+0x26723) (0x0033f184)
  8 0x004f0f0d in dis1_st (+0xf0f0c) (0x0033fa68)
  9 0x004f25eb in dis1_st (+0xf25ea) (0x0033fa7c)
  10 0x004fdf36 in dis1_st (+0xfdf35) (0x0033faa0)
  11 0x004a4e5b in dis1_st (+0xa4e5a) (0x0033fba4)
  12 0x00488cd3 in dis1_st (+0x88cd2) (0x0033fc28)
  13 0x0048c62e in dis1_st (+0x8c62d) (0x0033fc40)
  14 0x0043ccdc in dis1_st (+0x3ccdb) (0x0033fcd0)
  15 0x00510d5b in dis1_st (+0x110d5a) (0x0033fdc4)
  16 0x00523e4b in dis1_st (+0x123e4a) (0x0033fe10)
  17 0x7b461992 call_process_entry+0x11() in kernel32 (0x0033fe28)
  18 0x7b462c48 in kernel32 (+0x52c47) (0x0033fe68)
  19 0x7bc848ac call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x0033fe98)
  20 0x7bc8795d call_thread_func+0xfc() in ntdll (0x0033ff98)
  21 0x7bc8488a RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x0033ffb8)
  22 0x7bc57436 in ntdll (+0x47435) (0x0033ffe8)
  23 0xf75a1d9d wine_call_on_stack+0x1c() in libwine.so.1 (0x00000000)
  24 0xf75a1f00 wine_switch_to_stack+0x1f() in libwine.so.1 (0xffbdea68)
  25 0x7bc5b866 LdrInitializeThunk+0x265() in ntdll (0xffbdeac8)
  26 0x7b46910a __wine_kernel_init+0xa69() in kernel32 (0xffbdfc38)
  27 0x7bc5c813 __wine_process_init+0x162() in ntdll (0xffbdfca8)
  28 0xf759ff57 wine_init+0x2c6() in libwine.so.1 (0xffbdfd08)
  29 0x7c000c42 main+0x81() in <wine-loader> (0xffbe0168)
  30 0xf73b4637 __libc_start_main+0xf6() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0x60ed0c7c: flds    0x0(%ebp)
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (156 modules)
PE    400000-  975000   Export          dis1_st
PE    980000-  aa4000   Deferred        gameoverlayrenderer
PE   4140000- 427a000   Deferred        steam
PE  10000000-10008000   Deferred        alut
PE  30000000-302c1000   Deferred        steam2
PE  38000000-38a20000   Deferred        steamclient
PE  3b400000-3b438000   Deferred        steam_api
PE  3f000000-3f111000   Deferred        tier0_s
PE  3f600000-3f656000   Deferred        vstdlib_s
PE  60000000-60021000   Deferred        cserhelper
ELF 60d43000-613fd000   Dwarf           i965_dri.so
ELF 7a800000-7a935000   Dwarf           opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7a820000-7a935000   \               opengl32
ELF 7b400000-7b7e4000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b410000-7b7e4000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcfd000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcfd000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bd01000-7bd2c000   Deferred        winepulse<elf>
  \-PE  7bd10000-7bd2c000   \               winepulse
ELF 7bd2c000-7bd4f000   Deferred        mmdevapi<elf>
  \-PE  7bd30000-7bd4f000   \               mmdevapi
ELF 7c000000-7c004000   Dwarf           <wine-loader>
ELF 7c634000-7c66b000   Deferred        libtxc_dxtn.so
ELF 7c854000-7c86a000   Deferred        winejoystick<elf>
  \-PE  7c860000-7c86a000   \               winejoystick
ELF 7c86a000-7c876000   Deferred        libpciaccess.so.0
ELF 7c876000-7c89b000   Deferred        libdrm_intel.so.1
ELF 7c89b000-7c8bc000   Deferred        libudev.so.1
ELF 7c9e2000-7ca0e000   Deferred        libvorbis.so.0
ELF 7ca0e000-7ca17000   Deferred        libogg.so.0
ELF 7ca17000-7ca2d000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7ca2d000-7caa2000   Deferred        libpcre.so.3
ELF 7caa2000-7cabb000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7cabb000-7cb47000   Deferred        libvorbisenc.so.2
ELF 7cb47000-7cba7000   Deferred        libflac.so.8
ELF 7cba7000-7cc56000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
ELF 7cc56000-7cc7c000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF 7cc7c000-7cca2000   Deferred        libselinux.so.1
ELF 7cca2000-7cca9000   Deferred        libasyncns.so.0
ELF 7cca9000-7cd22000   Deferred        libsndfile.so.1
ELF 7cd22000-7cd2c000   Deferred        libwrap.so.0
ELF 7cd2c000-7cdba000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
ELF 7cdba000-7ce14000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7ce14000-7ce9c000   Deferred        libpulsecommon-8.0.so
ELF 7ce9c000-7cea8000   Deferred        libjson-c.so.2
ELF 7cea8000-7cf02000   Deferred        libpulse.so.0
ELF 7d204000-7d20d000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7d20d000-7d299000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF 7d299000-7d2ce000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.4
ELF 7d2ce000-7d30a000   Deferred        libnettle.so.6
ELF 7d30a000-7d31f000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7d31f000-7d353000   Deferred        libidn.so.11
ELF 7d353000-7d3b4000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d3b4000-7d50c000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF 7d512000-7d520000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF 7d520000-7d52a000   Deferred        libdrm_nouveau.so.2
ELF 7d531000-7d561000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7d540000-7d561000   \               netapi32
ELF 7d561000-7d593000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  7d570000-7d593000   \               secur32
ELF 7d593000-7d6c6000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7d5b0000-7d6c6000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7d6c6000-7d735000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d6d0000-7d735000   \               setupapi
ELF 7d735000-7d79b000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE  7d740000-7d79b000   \               dbghelp
ELF 7d79b000-7d7b6000   Deferred        imagehlp<elf>
  \-PE  7d7a0000-7d7b6000   \               imagehlp
ELF 7d7b6000-7d7e0000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d7c0000-7d7e0000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7d7e0000-7d8b0000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  7d7f0000-7d8b0000   \               crypt32
ELF 7d8b0000-7d8ea000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7d8c0000-7d8ea000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7d90e000-7d919000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7da01000-7da4a000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7da4a000-7da75000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7da75000-7da90000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7da90000-7db40000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7db40000-7db53000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7db53000-7db60000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7db85000-7dc13000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7db90000-7dc13000   \               winex11
ELF 7dc13000-7dc27000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7dc20000-7dc27000   \               psapi
ELF 7dc27000-7dca7000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7dc30000-7dca7000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7dca7000-7dde0000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7dcc0000-7dde0000   \               ole32
ELF 7dde0000-7de04000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7ddf0000-7de04000   \               imm32
ELF 7de04000-7dee6000   Deferred        msvcr120<elf>
  \-PE  7de20000-7dee6000   \               msvcr120
ELF 7dee6000-7e000000   Deferred        msvcp120<elf>
  \-PE  7df20000-7e000000   \               msvcp120
ELF 7e000000-7e015000   Deferred        xinput1_3<elf>
  \-PE  7e010000-7e015000   \               xinput1_3
ELF 7e015000-7e0d6000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7e030000-7e0d6000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7e0d6000-7e0df000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7e0df000-7e156000   Deferred        libopenal.so.1
ELF 7e157000-7e15b000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7e15b000-7e167000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7e167000-7e17b000   Deferred        xinput9_1_0<elf>
  \-PE  7e170000-7e17b000   \               xinput9_1_0
ELF 7e17b000-7e1f3000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e190000-7e1f3000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e1f3000-7e4b2000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e200000-7e4b2000   \               shell32
ELF 7e4b2000-7e4b9000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7e4b9000-7e4bd000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7e4bd000-7e4cf000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF 7e4cf000-7e4d6000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7e4d6000-7e4fc000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7e4fc000-7e502000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF 7e502000-7e51d000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF 7e51d000-7e668000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7e668000-7e66b000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF 7e66b000-7e672000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7e672000-7e676000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF 7e676000-7e68b000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7e68b000-7e6a7000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF 7e6a7000-7e6d1000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e6d1000-7e6ee000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7e865000-7e8d4000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7e8d4000-7e94e000   Deferred        libglu.so.1
ELF 7e951000-7e955000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7e955000-7e973000   Deferred        openal32<elf>
  \-PE  7e960000-7e973000   \               openal32
ELF 7e973000-7e98b000   Deferred        glu32<elf>
  \-PE  7e980000-7e98b000   \               glu32
ELF 7e98b000-7ea02000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9a0000-7ea02000   \               advapi32
ELF 7ea02000-7eb32000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea10000-7eb32000   \               gdi32
ELF 7eb32000-7ec88000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb40000-7ec88000   \               user32
ELF 7ec88000-7ed41000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7ec90000-7ed41000   \               winmm
ELF 7ed41000-7ed54000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ed54000-7ed61000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ed61000-7ed7c000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ed7c000-7ed86000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7ef86000-7efdb000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efdb000-7efde000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF 7efde000-7efe6000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF 7efe6000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f7392000-f7396000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF f7397000-f739c000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f739c000-f7552000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f7553000-f7570000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7590000-f7594000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF f7595000-f7764000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7766000-f778b000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f778d000-f778e000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    00000021    0
    00000020    0
    00000016    0
    00000012    0
    0000000f    0
00000010 explorer.exe
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000026    0
    00000025    0
    00000011    0
00000014 winedevice.exe
    00000024    0
    0000001b    0
    0000001a    0
    00000015    0
0000001e plugplay.exe
    00000023    0
    00000022    0
    0000001f    0
00000029 Steam.exe
    000001c2    0
    000001bf    0
    000001ba    0
    000001a1    0
    0000004d    0
    0000004c    0
    0000004b    0
    00000048    0
    00000047    0
    00000046    0
    00000045    0
    00000044    0
    00000043    0
    00000042    0
    00000040    0
    0000003f    0
    0000003e   15
    0000003d    0
    0000003c    0
    0000003b    0
    0000003a    0
    00000038    1
    00000035    0
    00000033    0
    00000032    0
    00000030    0
    0000002f    0
    0000002e    0
    0000002b    0
    0000002a    0
000001f0 (D) C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\Disgaea PC\dis1_st.exe
    00000060    0
    00000056    0
    00000054    0
    00000052    0
    0000004f    0
    00000049    0
    0000004a    0
    00000034    0
    00000039    0
    00000037    0
    00000036    0
    0000002d    0
    00000018    0
    0000001c    0
    00000019    0
    0000001d    0
    0000000c    0
    0000000d    0
    00000008    0
    00000009    0
    0000000a    0
    0000000b    0
    00000207    0
    00000206    0
    00000205    0
    00000204    0
    00000203    0
    00000202    0
    00000201    0
    00000200    0
    000001ff    0
    000001fe    0
    000001fd    0
    000001fc    0
    000001fb    0
    000001fa    0
    000001f9    0
    000001f8    0
    000001f7    0
    000001f1    2 <==
00000058 GameOverlayUI.exe
    00000064    0
    00000062    0
    0000005a    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-2.0-rc2 (Staging)
    Platform: i386
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.4.0-57-generic
```

i was wondering if there is something i can do to fix the issue. i can run the game but when i click start or if i continue to load my file, it crashes and i get this code.

Comment: The game has no results at WineHQ database which means it hasn't been tested or has it but no-one bothered to report the results. The error message suggests a memory management problem that I'm afraid has no solution at the moment. Also it most likely has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: oh i see, so then there is no way then?

Comment: I know only that it works on CrossOver (it is like a paid version of Wine): https://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/crossover/disgaea

Comment: interesting, makes me wonder how they figured it all out

Comment: You can try the trial version of Crossover and install the game with it and noting down what additional elements Crossover installs before the game itself... Then try to install the exact same components alongside Wine with the help of PlayOnLinux and/or Winetricks. It may work but if not consider buying a Crossover license.

Comment: ooo thats a good idea, i'll try that